# How to decompress and read huge (1-10+ GB) compressed files (gzip, zip, parquet) using AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, gzip, parquet, large-files

Questions similar to this have been posted a few times but not since the memory, storage and lifespan of AWS Lambdas have increased/improved which might open up other solutions, so I'm asking again.

We have 100's of TB's of data in S3 and have a requirement to read the files on a large scale looking for certain values. Some of these files are compressed with .zip, .gzip, Parquet, etc. and can be 1-10gb or larger in size.

We are considering AWS Lambda for security and performance reasons but I am looking at how we could handle these large compressed files.  I know that EC2 or ECS may be a better solution in some ways but for the purpose of this question I'd like to talk only about options with Lambdas.

Lambdas live for 15 minutes so any long running job is problematic.  Some files might simply be too large to even download from S3 in 15 minutes. Others could be downloaded and could then be split among other lambdas for processing. But many compressed files can't be split before being decompressed. Some compression algorithms like [pigz](https://zlib.net/pigz/) allow decompressing in parallel but we have no control over how the files are written and they can be written with numerous algorithms. By reading the header and footer it might be possible to split a Parquet file into chunks small enough that can be reliably read in less than 15 minutes but this is not so with large .gzip files for example.

If the file were uncompressed and split by one lambda and sent or streamed somehow to a fleet of others, the original lambda would time out so the uncompressed data would have to be stored somewhere. This would require moving from a stateless to stateful architecture where the uncompressed data would have to be written somewhere such as EFS. This complicates the architecture and mitigates some of the security benefits of being serverless because the data is stored more persistently. The lambdas would essentially operate on a decompressed copy of the data, temporarily until the processing was done and they could be deleted, so like a decompressed local cache.

Even so, it might take more than 15 minutes to decompress a huge file and you generally can't pick up on a partially complete decompression where you left off. And decompressing a huge file would require a large amount of storage, at least temporarily, and the associated cost. We could potentially just copy the compressed file into EFS, in chunks if necessary, and decompress it from there, but even so files over a certain size couldn't be decompressed even this way.

We could simply rule out files above a certain size but I am trying to think if there are options that I have not considered.

Comment: I don't feel that Lambda is the way to go.  If you don't want to go the EC2 route then take a look at [step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).  You've got a workflow and that's really what they are for.  And the maximum run time is 1 year.

Comment: It isn't clear to me how orchestrating lambdas with step functions alleviates or gets around the problems associated with the 15 minute lifespan of lambdas?

Comment: @UncleLongHair see my comment to your comment under my answer for how Step Functions helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the conversion with Athena and use Lambda and possibly Step Functions to orchestrate the process.

I don't think you should build your own map/reduce platform on Lambda, it will be a lot of work, and it won't be the best tool for the job. However, Lambda is a great way to control other AWS services.

Athena has a feature called ["CTAS"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html) (short for `CREATE TABLE AS`), which can be used to transform a data set into a new data set using SQL. The new data set can be in any file format supported by Athena, including Parquet.

What you could do is create tables for your existing "raw" data and then run CTAS operations to get new clean and columnar data sets. When you are done you can just throw away the Athena tables, they are just metadata – dropping an Athena table leaves the data in place on S3.

Since it can take quite a while to convert a couple of GB you might want to look at Step Functions to avoid having to keep your Lambda functions idle while Athena is working. You can create a state machine where one step kicks off the conversion by setting up the raw table, and generate the CTAS SQL, then use a wait step to poll for completion, and a final step that cleans up and notifies something that the conversion is done.

There is unfortunately a problem with ZIP files: Athena does not support ZIP archives (it supports compressed files, but ZIP, like TAR are archive formats). You will have to unpack archives before conversion. This should be possible to do in Lambda too, but you need a good library that allows you to do it without having to copy the whole ZIP into the Lambda environment since that could make you run out of both memory and disk space.

Comment: The problem is that above a certain size, the time spent reading the file exceeds the lifespan of the lambda. Say I have a 500GB Parquet file that takes 60 minutes to read. The lambda only lives for 15 minutes. If I create an Athena dataset with CTAS I still have to read that same data to the same Lambda. Even if Athena is twice as fast the lambda will still die before it finishes reading.

Comment: Your Lambda doesn't need to run while the query runs, that's the beauty of using Step Functions for the orchestration. The function starts the query, and you poll for completion using Step Functions, calling another function when the query completes. Since I wrote my answer Step Functions has even gotten native support for Athena, so you can start a query directly as a step: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/aws-step-functions-now-supports-amazon-athena-service-integration/

Comment: Maybe it was not clear in my original question but the fundamental task is to read the contents of the files looking for certain values. So every byte of every file has to be read and run through regex/ML/lookup logic, it is not simply a matter of converting it from one format to another.  I understand how step functions can orchestrate Athena queries but then some component will need to issue the queries, read the data and run it through custom code to find values. That is the part that is currently done with EC2's which I'm exploring doing with Lambdas somehow.

Comment: Athena's API is asynchronous, a Lambda function doesn't need to wait while Athena runs a query, it can start a query and another Lambda function (or another invocation) can process the result of the query when it has completed. It's not like JDBC where the process that starts a query must hang around waiting for the response.